# How to set Dictionary as Dictionary value in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I want to set a dictionary as dictionary value?
But it throws an error like

> 'Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment'.

How to fix this issue?

```
sub test()
Dim Dict As Scripting.Dictionary
Set Dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim rows As Scripting.Dictionary
Set rows = New Scripting.Dictionary 

dict("name") = "Sarah"
dict("surname") = "Jones"

rows(dict("name")) = dict

end sub
```

Comment: `Dictionary` is an `Object` type, you seem to be missing the requierd `Set` keyword when assigning object types, try `Set rows(dict("name")) = dict`, although this looks somewhat suspect as you're assigning the full `dict` to the `"name"` key that belongs to `dict`.

Comment: @DavidZemens - you can add key/items to dictionaries like that without needing `Set`, I guess because you are not actually assigning an object.

Comment: @DavidZemens - that said, think you nailed it, given the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Dictionary` is an object type, with a *default member*.

```
rows(dict("name")) = dict
```

The RHS of this assignment is really a call to `dict.Item`, but invoked without any parameters... but the `Key` parameter is *required* - hence the error.

[image]

The `Set` keyword disambiguates default member calls from "yes I really mean *the object reference itself*"

```
Set rows(dict("name")) = dict
```

Comment: So `Set` is not required on the other assignments because they are not objects?

Comment: @SJR there are two types of assignments in VBA: `Let`, and `Set` - for value and reference assignments, respectively. The `Let` keyword is obsolete and can be omitted, but without the `Set` keyword, when the RHS is an object you (attempt to) let-coerce the object through a default member call. If there is no default member, you get error 438. If there is one but it's parameterized, you get the error the OP got. VB.NET objects removed the concept of default members, hence the `Set` keyword disappeared too.

Comment: @SJR Huh, apparently [you can have default members in vb.net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-declare-and-call-a-default-property). I stand flabbergasted, but happy to see [it's explicitly and unequivocally, heavily discouraged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-declare-and-call-a-default-property#robust-programming), and the considerations in that paragraph absolutely apply to VBA code as well.

Comment: "You cannot define a default property that does not take at least one argument." - and that's how `Set` could be removed; they made the ambiguous situation a compiler error.